# Move down empty rows when using RowSorter.SortKey on JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, rowsorter

I'm trying to use **JTable** to show data from excel files.

I'm using `RowSorter.SortKey`, so I can order many columns:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < x; i++){                    
   sortKeys.add(new RowSorter.SortKey(i,  order));
 }

 sorter.setSortKeys(sortKeys);           
 sorter.sort();
```

The problem is that the empty rows are put at the top during **ascending** order.
Is there way to keep using the JTable sorting function but moving empty rows at the end of the JTable?

Thank you
P.S.: I'm new to java swing.

Comment: You may be new to Swing but you are not new to the forum. You continue to ask lots of questions, but rarely "accept" answers when you get help, or even comment on why the suggestion doesn't work, so I'll skip this. Also you should be post an [mre] with every question so we can see exactly what you are doing.

Comment: You are right man. I try to thank every one helping me, but from time to time I miss to check some of posts.

Comment: What @camickr means is not that you say "thank you" or not, but that if we go to your question history, your first page that shows 30 questions, has only 7 of them accepted which is only a 23% of acceptance rate, if we remove the closed ones that would be 7 / 27 which is still a 25% of acceptance rate for ONLY the first page. By now that you have almost 2K rep you should know that "Thank you" and "P.S. ..." are just noise in the question. Instead of adding those create a brand new program that isolates your issue and post that code here

Comment: Have a look at this: [SummaryTableSorter](https://github.com/santhosh-tekuri/MyBlog/blob/master/SummaryTableSorting/src/santhosh/SummaryTableSorter.java) which you can find on GitHub. What it does: makes it so that the last line in the model will always remain the last row in the view (a summary line). What it illustrates: creating your own row sorter that imposes a special ordering. What you can do: tweak it to check for empty lines in the model instead of checking for the last line in the model. The repo also has a demo on the use of the SummaryTableSorter class. Good luck!

Comment: @TT thank you for your advice. I solved my problem creating my own comparator that moves empty rows at the end.